# How to fix encoding issues of pydicom in python

Tags: python, dicom, pydicom

This is the code:

```
import dicom

ds = dicom.read_file(FILE_PATH)
print(ds)
```

Error:

```
LookupError: unknown encoding: ISO 2022 IR 100
```

When using pydicom in order to look at data, I got the error above.
I found  'ISO 2022 IR 100': 'latin_1' ,according to [here](https://github.com/pydicom/pydicom/blob/master/pydicom/charset.py).

However, I didn't get how to fix this problem.
Can you help me to solve this error?

Comment: That encoding was [added two years ago](https://github.com/pydicom/pydicom/pull/211). Can you verify that you are running an up-to-date version of pydicom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, the culprit was an out-of-date version of pydicom. Upgrading to a more recent version fixed this issue.

Comment: As following comment and your answer, I've upgrade pydicom from git and then the problem is solved. 
(pydicom version is now 1.0.0a1 from 0.9.9 )

What I did is: 

1. upgrade pydicom by terminal
pip install git+https://github.com/pydicom/pydicom.git

2. Change python code a bit
import dicom -> import pydicom as dicom

Then, it works!!.
Cheers

Comment: Above is slightly wrong. 
2. pip install git+https://github.com/pydicom/pydicom.git