# Encoding issue while reading dicom repo

Tags: python-3.x, dicom, pydicom

I am preprocessing a DICOM images repository to feed with it a convolutional neural network, but when I try to read the repository it throws me the following error:

> LookupError: unknown encoding: ISO 2022 IR 100

Here is the code I used :

```py
listoflists = []
list = []
for x in range(1, 10):
    data_path = "/home/lorenzo_f/CT COLONOGRAPHY/1.3.6.1.4.1.9328.50.4.000%d" %x 
    output_path ="/home/lorenzo_f/output/"
    subfolders = [f.path for f in os.scandir(data_path) if f.is_dir() ]    
    subfolder = [f.path for f in os.scandir(subfolders[0]) if f.is_dir() ]  
    list.append(load_scan(subfolder[0]))
    list.append(load_scan(subfolder[1]))
    listoflists.append((list))
```

Using the function `load_scan`

```py
# Loop over the image files and store everything into a list.

def load_scan(path):
    slices = [dicom.read_file(path + '/' + s) for s in os.listdir(path)]
    #slices[0].SpecificCharacterSet = 'latin_1'
    slices.sort(key = lambda x: int(x.InstanceNumber))
    try:
        slice_thickness = np.abs(slices[0].ImagePositionPatient[2] - slices[1].ImagePositionPatient[2])
    except:
        slice_thickness = np.abs(slices[0].SliceLocation - slices[1].SliceLocation)

    for s in slices:
        s.SliceThickness = slice_thickness

    return slices
```

I can not find the tag you are saying, this is the code I used and the first entry of the output

```
data_path = "/home/lorenzo_f/CT COLONOGRAPHY/1.3.6.1.4.1.9328.50.4.0010"
output_path ="/home/lorenzo_f/output/"
subfolders = [f.path for f in os.scandir(data_path) if f.is_dir() ]    
subfolder = [f.path for f in os.scandir(subfolders[0]) if f.is_dir() ]
ds=load_scan(subfolder[0])
ds
```

````
 (0008, 0008) Image Type                          CS: ['ORIGINAL', 'SECONDARY', 'AXIAL']
 (0008, 0016) SOP Class UID                       UI: CT Image Storage
 (0008, 0018) SOP Instance UID                    UI: 1.3.6.1.4.1.9328.50.4.9867
 (0008, 0020) Study Date                          DA: '20000101'
 (0008, 0021) Series Date                         DA: '20000101'
 (0008, 0022) Acquisition Date                    DA: '20000101'
 (0008, 0023) Content Date                        DA: '20000101'
 (0008, 0030) Study Time                          TM: '091936'
 (0008, 0032) Acquisition Time                    TM: '092131'
 (0008, 0033) Content Time                        TM: '101416'
 (0008, 0050) Accession Number                    SH: ''
 (0008, 0060) Modality                            CS: 'CT'
 (0008, 0070) Manufacturer                        LO: 'GE MEDICAL SYSTEMS'
 (0008, 0080) Institution Name                    LO: ''
 (0008, 0081) Institution Address                 ST: ''
 (0008, 0090) Referring Physician's Name          PN: 'xDONEx'
 (0008, 1030) Study Description                   LO: 'CT COLONOGRAP C'
 (0008, 103e) Series Description                  LO: 'CT COLONOGRAPHY'
 (0008, 1048) Physician(s) of Record              PN: ' '
 (0008, 1090) Manufacturer's Model Name           LO: 'LightSpeed16'
 (0008, 1140)  Referenced Image Sequence   0 item(s) ---- 
 (0008, 2112)  Source Image Sequence   0 item(s) ---- 
 (0010, 0010) Patient's Name                      PN: '1.3.6.1.4.1.9328.50.4.0010'
 (0010, 0020) Patient ID                          LO: '1.3.6.1.4.1.9328.50.4.0010'
 (0010, 0030) Patient's Birth Date                DA: ''
 (0010, 0040) Patient's Sex                       CS: 'M'
 (0010, 1000) Other Patient IDs                   LO: ''
 (0010, 1010) Patient's Age                       AS: '068Y'
 (0010, 21b0) Additional Patient History          LT: 'COLON SCREENING'
 (0010, 21c0) Pregnancy Status                    US: []
 (0012, 0010) Clinical Trial Sponsor Name         LO: ''
 (0012, 0020) Clinical Trial Protocol ID          LO: ''
 (0012, 0021) Clinical Trial Protocol Name        LO: ''
 (0012, 0030) Clinical Trial Site ID              LO: ''
 (0012, 0031) Clinical Trial Site Name            LO: ''
 (0012, 0040) Clinical Trial Subject ID           LO: ''
 (0012, 0042) Clinical Trial Subject Reading ID   LO: ''
 (0013, 0010) Private Creator                     LO: 'CTP'
 (0013, 1010) Private tag data                    UN: b'CT COLONOGRAPHY\x00'
 (0013, 1013) Private tag data                    UN: b'70093008'
 (0018, 0015) Body Part Examined                  CS: 'COLON'
 (0018, 0022) Scan Options                        CS: 'HELICAL MODE'
 (0018, 0050) Slice Thickness                     DS: '0.7999999999999989'
 (0018, 0060) KVP                                 DS: '120'
 (0018, 0090) Data Collection Diameter            DS: '500.000000'
 (0018, 1020) Software Version(s)                 LO: 'LightSpeedverrel'
 (0018, 1030) Protocol Name                       LO: '6.10 CT  COLONOGRAPHY'
 (0018, 1100) Reconstruction Diameter             DS: '330.000000'
 (0018, 1110) Distance Source to Detector         DS: '949.075012'
 (0018, 1111) Distance Source to Patient          DS: '541.000000'
 (0018, 1120) Gantry/Detector Tilt                DS: '0.000000'
 (0018, 1130) Table Height                        DS: '167.199997'
 (0018, 1140) Rotation Direction                  CS: 'CW'
 (0018, 1150) Exposure Time                       IS: '526'
 (0018, 1151) X-Ray Tube Current                  IS: '140'
 (0018, 1152) Exposure                            IS: '2286'
 (0018, 1160) Filter Type                         SH: 'BODY FILTER'
 (0018, 1170) Generator Power                     IS: '16800'
 (0018, 1190) Focal Spot(s)                       DS: '0.700000'
 (0018, 1200) Date of Last Calibration            DA: ''
 (0018, 1201) Time of Last Calibration            TM: ''
 (0018, 1210) Convolution Kernel                  SH: 'STANDARD'
 (0018, 5100) Patient Position                    CS: 'FFS'
 (0020, 000d) Study Instance UID                  UI: 1.3.6.1.4.1.9328.50.4.9864
 (0020, 000e) Series Instance UID                 UI: 1.3.6.1.4.1.9328.50.4.9865
 (0020, 0010) Study ID                            SH: '1'
 (0020, 0011) Series Number                       IS: '102'
 (0020, 0012) Acquisition Number                  IS: '1'
 (0020, 0013) Instance Number                     IS: '1'
 (0020, 0032) Image Position (Patient)            DS: ['-165.000000', '-165.000000', '-8.335000']
 (0020, 0037) Image Orientation (Patient)         DS: ['1.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000', '1.000000', '0.000000']
 (0020, 0052) Frame of Reference UID              UI: 1.3.6.1.4.1.9328.50.4.9866
 (0020, 1040) Position Reference Indicator        LO: 'XY'
 (0020, 1041) Slice Location                      DS: '-8.335000'
 (0028, 0002) Samples per Pixel                   US: 1
 (0028, 0004) Photometric Interpretation          CS: 'MONOCHROME2'
 (0028, 0010) Rows                                US: 512
 (0028, 0011) Columns                             US: 512
 (0028, 0030) Pixel Spacing                       DS: ['0.644531', '0.644531']
 (0028, 0100) Bits Allocated                      US: 16
 (0028, 0101) Bits Stored                         US: 16
 (0028, 0102) High Bit                            US: 15
 (0028, 0103) Pixel Representation                US: 1
 (0028, 0120) Pixel Padding Value                 SS: -2000
 (0028, 1050) Window Center                       DS: '40'
 (0028, 1051) Window Width                        DS: '400'
 (0028, 1052) Rescale Intercept                   DS: '-1024'
 (0028, 1053) Rescale Slope                       DS: '1'
 (0040, a124) UID                                 UI: ''
 (0088, 0140) Storage Media File-set UID          UI: ''
 (3006, 0024) Referenced Frame of Reference UID   UI: ''
 (3006, 00c2) Related Frame of Reference UID      UI: ''
 (7fe0, 0010) Pixel Data                          OW: Array of 524288 bytes,```
````

Comment: Specific Character Set (0008,0005) appears to be missing (which means that the dataset is encoded in US-ASCII - seems to be the case when I look at the attribute values). But the message you receive is clearly related to it. So either it is omitted from the dump or it is a weird bug in the toolkit you are using.

Comment: This was known issue in older versions of pydicom. Are you using latest release? Refer [this](https://bitbucket.org/openrem/openrem/issues/532) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45528897/5779732).

Comment: I am using pydicom 1.2.2

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that your issue is related to the Transfer Syntax. The error message suggests that the Specific Character Set (0008,0005) has a value of

> ISO 2022 IR 100

ISO 2022 is only allowed if so-called code extension techniques are used. That means, the same attribute value can contain characters obtained from different character sets and special byte sequences (defined in ISO 2022) are used to switch between them.

For Reference, see PS3.3, C.12.1.1.2

Code extension techniques are comparably hard to handle thus very rarely used. In fact, this is the first case in which I (probably) see such an object. This is very interesting for me as well - so would you mind to share the manufacturer and device which created this image?

How can you solve this issue? Good question. I am unaware of any (python) toolkit which is capable of handling this string encoding - maybe dcm4che can do this.

If you just want to extract the pixel data, then it might be worth a try to change the value of (0008,0005) to "ISO_IR 100". This may lead to issues in reading meta data like patient name or study description. But all attributes related to pixel data encoding are not affected by character encoding, so it should work.

Comment: https://wiki.cancerimagingarchive.net/display/Public/CT+COLONOGRAPHY#2ef3776591bf4fccbe6bb1197180474c

Comment: Thanks for the link. Do you have a tip how to handle "tcia" files?

Comment: yes, you have to download the NBIA Data Retriever, a software that you can download here https://wiki.cancerimagingarchive.net/display/NBIA/Downloading+TCIA+Images#DownloadingTCIAImages-DownloadingtheNBIADataRetriever

Comment: Is it "ISO 2022 IR 100" or "ISO_IR 100"?

Comment: Thanks for the link to the downloader. But it does not start on my system (needs a manifest)

Comment: The error thrown is "LookupError: unknown encoding: ISO 2022 IR 100", but when i checked tag (0008,0005) it has value "ISO_IR 100" far all the files in my repository.

Comment: `(0008, 0005) Specific Character Set              CS: 'ISO_IR 100'`